# Apache2.4/nginx - route all traffic to requesting host?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I want to create a server that acts as a loopback to the requesting machine on a particular subdomain.

How do I reference the requesting IP to route traffic on a handful of ports back to the requesting IP?

Alternatively a clone of xip.io running on my own subdomains would work, so routing like this:

10.199.1.1.my.domain.com -> routes all traffic to 10.199.1.1

Comment: **If** this is possible at all, it would likely use `mod_proxy`. That said, I highly doubt it's possible. What is your use case here? Why can't clients just poll themselves?

Comment: I'm using internal infrastructure for a number of services, and the only way to get it to work is https and getting cookies from a different domain. IPs change dynamically.

I could also get by with 10.113.12.10.server.com routing to 10.113.12.10, if that's easier.

Comment: This definitely looks like the wrong way to solve some standard problem.

Comment: What's even more helpful, - it's the question about weird way to solve your problem instead of the question about the problem itself. But you know, it's up to you. Nobody owns you anything. I was just trying to warn you from shooting your own leg, but you can proceed.

Comment: drookie's question [is perfectly valid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) and deserves a real answer.

Comment: @MichaelHamptonhere is no "problem itself." The problem is that certain services only accept requests from certain domains, and my specific problem *requires* that a handful of subdirectories go one place, and all other traffic go elsewhere. It's not a good server setup, and I'm not defending it. 

What I'm saying is that the problem statement is accurate, and I have more of a chance of winning the lottery than addressing the underlying problem -> these services don't work locally or from external domains. I don't control them. I need xip.io on my intranet.

Comment: Preferably I could grab the incoming IP, like I mentioned. That would be a bit easier for myself and others who may use this than the xip.io solution of routing to the prefix in the domain. But either solves my technical issue and I could live with the slight degradation in functionality.

Comment: @StefanKendall Have you tried out anything with `mod_proxy` on this? As I mentioned before, it's highly likely that this will not work with any pre-existing solution. You may need to consider the fact that you'll need to develop a custom solution to solve your problem. This is likely what xip.io did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking to do is disgustingly wrong and should not be allowed anywhere near a the public internet or any production environment - you're opening up some potentially catastrophic security holes that WILL result in a problem for you at some point in the future.

As a professional it is your job to ensure that your superiors are aware of the problems in what's being implemented and help them find a solution that *ISN'T* bad, wrong and dangerous. Dealing with that is left as an exercise for the reader (if you want assistance with that try asking the folks over on [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

---

All that said, if you absolutely ***must*** implement a bad idea because your superiors are intransigent the way to do it is usually Apache's mod_rewrite - that module LOVES to do terrible things.

You can implement the `xp.io`-alike option with `mod_rewrite` by capturing URLS of the form `a.b.c.d.mydomain.com/xxxx` and issuing a redirect (301 or 302) to `http://a.b.c.d/xxxx`.

You could also implement automatic redirection using the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` mod_rewrite variable to automatically fill in the IP address if you wish.

These solutions are inherently fragile: For one they only work for HTTP/HTTPS traffic (if you want something else you'll need to implement a proper proxy solution). For another if the requestor is behind a NAT or proxy it will break (possibly in unpredictable or insecure ways).

Comment: This isn't for the public internet; this is specifically to support local development, and it's HTTP/S only.

Comment: @StefanKendall It's slightly less horrible in that case - the most egregious risk (cross-site scripting) is much more limited. I would however recommend against the `xp.io` style solution (because theoretically an external IP can be plugged into it and would then open up the potential for XSS again). Restricting access to the redirecting URLs (by password or ACL) would also be wise.

Comment: This is on an intranet not connected to the internet. If any machine on the network is compromised, there are much bigger problems than this that need fixing. Only a few people will ever use this, and REMOTE_ADDR seems like the better way to go anyway.

Comment: Yeah if you can rely on `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` being a real machine's address that works very well. (Alternatively if you can always assume `localhost` will serve what you need that's an option too - just slap that in there.)